# Button on the right issue

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, margin

I'm trying just to put a `commandButton` in a header of a panel components on the right margin. Sounds just an html issue, I don't know why doesn't work.

```
<p:panel id="panel" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <h:outputLabel value="#{partyBean.currentparty.name}" />
            <p:commandButton id="asktojoin" style="margin-right:10px" action="#{joinRequestBean.askForParty(partyBean.currentparty)}" value="Ask to Join">
            </p:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
    .....
```

the button appears on the left, close to the `outputLabel`.

Comment: bhdrk's answer seems nice, but otherwise style="float:right" should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<p:panel/> has a "actions" facet. you can put action buttons in this facet.

```
<p:panel id="panel" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{partyBean.currentparty.name}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="actions">
        <p:commandButton id="asktojoin" styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon "
                         action="#{joinRequestBean.askForParty(partyBean.currentparty)}" value="Ask to Join"/>
    </f:facet>

    ...

</p:panel>
```